# renderTable with Filter on Data in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on creating a simple app that would allow user to select a table name and that would open up the data table filtered for what they selected.

DT and DD:

```
DT<-sqlQuery(con,"Select distinct name from dbo.TableA")  
DD<-sqlQuery(con,"Select * from sys.TableB")
```

DT data is like this:

```
Name  
studenTbl  
parentTbl
classTbl
```

DD data is like this

```
Table_Name|Column      |Description  
studentTbl|student_ID  |ID of student  
studentTbl|student_Name|Name of student  
studentTbl|student_Age |Age of student  
parentTbl |parentID    |ID of parent   
parentTbl |parent_Name |Name of parent
```

UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list({DT}),
              tableOutput(outputId = "DataDictionary"))

)
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output) {



  output$DataDictionary<-renderTable({DD()})


}
```

DD is a dataset already in R with a Table_Name column that should be filtered with the input$dataset.

Right now, I get the selection combobox but when I select a table name, the dataset does not show. How do I fix this?

Comment: where is the DD() coming from? I don't see anywhere else in your app.

Comment: @MLavoie I updated the question for where does DD and DT come from? As I mentioned, it is a dataset already in R, and you can see how I got it.

Comment: ok DD is a data set and DT is a column or another data set?

Comment: @MLavoie Both are datasets. Table_Name is a column in DD that needs to be filtered based on the input by user

Comment: but the `input$dataset` is a dataset. How do you want to filter `Table_Name`, a column, with another dataset? I am sorry maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: @MLavoie This is a Shiny app. I am following this video:  https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/          "dataset" is the input ID used in the UI

Comment: I know it is a shiny app. You could filter a dataset with another column but not a column with another dataset. Anyway, your goal is not clear. Maybe someone else will understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another try. There were a couple of mistakes in your code, but this one should giving you what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
DT <- data.frame(Name = c("studenTbl", "parentTbl", "classTbl"))
DD <- data.frame(Table_Name = c("studenTbl", "studenTbl", "studenTbl", "parentTbl", "parentTbl"), Column = c("student_ID", "student_Name", "student_Age", "parentID", "parent_Name"), Description = c("ID of student", "Name of student", "Age of student", "ID of parent", "Name of parent"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Data set", DT$Name),
  tableOutput('DataDictionary')

) 

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$DataDictionary <- renderTable(

   DD_b <- DD %>% filter(Table_Name == input$dataset)

  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you MLavoie. Did not work for me. I have updated the question with mock data but If there is anything I can provide to help, let me know.

Comment: I am seeing the selectbox with DT and the table appears with DD. That part works. The only part now is when I select e.g. studentTbl then the tableOutput should be filtered for that TableName. I tried the commented script for filtering but that did not work

Comment: @SQLserving. sorry I forgot to uncomment some of the lines. see edits

Comment: getting an error where the table appears saying "could not find function "%>%"". I added library(magrittr) but still no joy. So I changed DD_b <- DD %>% filter(Table_Name == input$dataset) to DD[DD$Table_Name==input$dataset,] and it works. Thanks for the help!!(You can update your answer to show what worked for me and what worked for you incase somebody finds this helpful)

Comment: Btw, in order to use %>% you need to load `library(dplyr)`